# How does adding a "lives" mechanic change average picks?

Tags: combinatorics

I'm tuning a slot machine app and need to make sure the mini-game is appropriately balanced.

The mini-game is a grid of 30 treasure chests, 6 of which are traps.  The user continues to open chests (and earn prizes) until they hit a trap.

What I'd like to do is add a "lives" mechanic where hitting a trap depletes a life instead of ending the game outright.  When user is out of lives, the mini-game ends.

Here's the equation I'm using to determine the return %:

> $(return \ \text{%}) = (\text{%} \ chance \ of \ triggering) * (avg \
>  reward) * (avg \ num \ of \ picks)$

Here's the table I'm using to derive average number of picks:

```
Pick #     Probability     Expected  
1          20%             0.20  
2          16.55%          0.33  
3          13.60%          0.41  
4          11.08%          0.44  
5          8.95%           0.45
6          7.16%           0.43
7          5.67%           0.40
8          4.44%           0.35
9          3.43%           0.31
10         2.61%           0.26
11         1.96%           0.22
12         1.44%           0.17
13         1.04%           0.14
14         0.74%           0.10
15         0.51%           0.08
16         0.34%           0.05
17         0.22%           0.04
18         0.13%           0.02
19         0.08%           0.01
20         0.04%           0.01
21         0.02%           0.00
22         0.01%           0.00
23         0.00%           0.00
24         0.00%           0.00
25         0.00%           0.00
Total      100.00%         4.43
```

Here's the equation I'm using to determine probability:

> $(probability) = \frac{PERMUT(24, \ Pick \ \text{#} - 1) \ * \ (num \ of \ traps)}{PERMUT(30,
>  \ Pick \ \text{#})}$

How does adding a "lives" mechanic change these equations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given your definition of Probability (assuming you're sticking with 6 traps):

```
(probability)=PERMUT(24, Pick n−1)*6 / PERMUT(30, Pick n)
```

We arrive at the following sequence of terms (we are assuming $n > 3$ here, but a similar sequence can be expressed for any size of $n \leq 25$):

$$\frac{24}{30} \times \frac{23}{29} \times \frac{22}{28} \times ... \times \frac{6}{(30 - n + 1)}$$

For example, if the number of picks is $5$ then you have a probability of:

```
24/30 for getting the first pick not on a trap
23/29 for the second
22/28 for the third
21/27 for the fourth good pick
6/26 for hitting the trap

That's 24/30 * 23/29 * 22/28 * 21/27 * 6/26 = 0.08947833775
and 6/26 = 6/(30 - 5 + 1)
```

You can play with the numbers to see that this extends for all $n$.

Therefore, when you add in a 'lives' system you just need to change the terms to include more traps.

A choice of 5 but with 3 lives now extends to the following product sequence:

```
24/30 * 23/29 * 6/28 * 5/27 * 4/26 = 0.00387352111 chance of merely five picks

24/30 chance for a good pick
23/29 for another good pick
6/28 for a trap
5/27 for another trap
4/26 for one more trap
```

You may be thinking, hey, I could get a trap in the beginning and this should change the odds. But luckily this isn't true since the terms in the denominator (`30 * 29 * 28 * 27 * 26`) never change regardless of when you pick a trap.

We can thus derive the expression for 3 lives:

```
(probability) = PERMUT(24, Pick n-3)*6*5*4/PERMUT(30, Pick n)
```

Or more formally for any amount of lives:

```
P(n, lives) = PERMUT(24, Pick n-lives)*PURMUT(6, lives) / PERMUT(30, Pick n)
P(n < lives) = 0%
P(n == lives) = PERMUT(6, lives) / PERMUT(30, lives) given that PERMUT(24,0) = 1
```

Where in your base case lives would equal 1.

Comment: I had a couple of follow up questions: (1) What does probability look like for picks 1, 2 and 3?  (2) In the formal expression, you multiply the first permutation * 6 factorial.  But in the expression for three lives, you only multiply by 6, 5 and 4.  Why is this?

Comment: I changed my answer to reflect your questions.